# Using Rmagick with eventmachine

Tags: ruby, rmagick, eventmachine, ruby-grape, goliath

I am trying to create a very simple web service with Goliath and Grape. All that my service would do is that given an image path and a target dimension it would return the new geometry of the image. The images are stored in the same server as the host of the web service.

So I have this code within Grape:

```
# some Grape code omitted
get "/" do
  EM.defer {
    image = Magick::Image.read('path to image').first
    image.change_geometry('3000x3900') do |cols, row, img|
      return {width: cols, height: row}
    end
  }
end
```

When I visit the endpoint in the browser all I get is this string

```
"#<ConditionVariable:0x007ffd9de1f6e8>"
```

Without EM.defer it returns the following json but with very low requests/secs (about 4 reqs/sec):

```
{width: 'new width', height: 'new heigth'}
```

How could I make the Rmagick operations non blocking and make it return the results?

Comment: See http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#defer-class_method, `op` parameter is the `&block` from your code, it's executed in a separate thread, the `callback` parameter on the other hand is the block of code the reactor triggers once `EM.defer` returns the result. See if you can return response from EM.defer's callback block

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed things up a bit.

Call to `RMagick` is *always* blocking, since it requires the image to be processed. The good news is the call to `grape` itself is *non-blocking*. It means, that while your single clients must wait for claimed 1/3 secs to complete, *another* clients are still able to queue requests.

I guess your testing environment simply calls the respective service one-by-one, waiting for requests to complete. Instead of that you are to call the service from separate threads, getting results as they are ready.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am aware that Rmagick would block my application, hence I tried using EM.defer with it. Perhaps there is something wrong with my implementation of EM.defer?

Comment: I suggest you have `Sinatra` behind your `Grape`, right? You don’t need to re-implement `Sinatra` functionality, please refer to `threaded` option [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html). Anyway, implementing `EM#defer` inside of the `get` block is wrong, since client waits for the response here and you can’t prevent blocking from within already blocked method.

Comment: You can, however, not block the reactor thread for all other requests, this is why OP uses EM.defer